# Javascript access childNode

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following problem and I have not found a way to solve it. I'm using a dynamically generated table, which consists of 4 columns: a checkbox, text values ​​and a hidden input.

```
echo "<tr><td><div class='input-containerh'><input type='checkbox'></div></td>";
echo "<td>" .$s. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$L.  and some vars............    "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' value=" .  some vars.... "></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

As I want to format the checkbox, because in some browsers the cell makes me too big, I use a DIV to format input (checkbox) and it works good for me.

Now the problem is a javascript function that detect if the input was select and now does not work me:

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
```

Using firebug I found that the problem was:

```
var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
```

because it refers to "DIV" not at "input".

How i can reach the "input" element that is within "DIV" and  also inside the cell?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `row.cells[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0]` or maybe `row.cells[0].childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName("input")`?

Comment: try `console.log` on the `row.cells[0].childNodes` and navigate your way to the input

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown seems to have it right. Just need to go a level deeper.

Comment: @MiloLaMar almost: it should be `...getElementsByTagName("input")[0]`

Comment: I'm puzzled, I will have tested this code 10 times and did not work, but now it works. Had some error, of course! row.cells[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0] runs ok! Thank´s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0]` worked with this HTML:

```
<tr><td><input> type='checkbox'></td>
```

changing the HTML as follows:

```
<tr><td><div class='input-containerh'><input> type='checkbox'></div></td>
```

means that `row.cells[0].childNodes[0]` will now point to the `div` element. To get the `input` element inside `div`, you just access the next level of children with `childNodes`. So, in a nutshell, you can get access to your `input` with this:

```
var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
```

Comment: Hi, thank´s for response. but this does not work properly, text "type='checkbox'" is displayed. 
Apparently missing a "<" in your code not?

Comment: Response of  – DontVoteMeDown - (and your) childNodes[0].childNodes[0] they runs ok.

Answer (score 2):

(Just a comment)

If you use index to access child nodes, watch out:

```
<td><input ...></td>
```

behaves differently than

```
<td>
  <input ...>
</td>
```

In the first case, there is only one node in the td. In the second one, there are three: the first one is a text node containing end of line and two spaces, the second one is the HTMLInputElement and the third one is again text node containing end of line.

Comment: For over 30 minutes I've been pulling my hair out for this answer.

Comment: @amallard there is also ParentNode.children property which returns live collection of nodes, skipping non-Element child nodes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children

Answer (score 1):

This is what the HTML looks like, together with the JavaScript objects:

```
<tr><td><div class='input-containerh'><input type='checkbox'></div></td>
    ^
    |   ^
    |   +--- row.cells[0].firstChild
    |
    +------- row.cells[0]
```

As you can see, `row.cells[0].firstChild` points to the `<div class="input-containerh">`; so you need to go one further:

```
row.cells[0].firstChild.firstChild
```

Comment: I use childNodes, but the theory is the same!. Thx.